# Can we use the duality notation such that the second variable is an element of the measure space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, duality-theorems

I read article ***New Sequential Compactness Results for Spaces of Scalarly Integrable Functions*** by Erik J. Balder, on page 8 : Author defined  the function $a: T\times E\to \mathbb{R}$  by the usual duality between $E$  and $E^*=F$ $( ⟨.,.⟩)$ such that:
$$
a(t,x)=\langle x, t\rangle
$$
But normally the second variable $(t\in T)$  must be an element of dual of $E$, right? Why does the author make this notation?

An idea please 
[image]

Comment: If we write " $\langle x, t\rangle, y$ "  then  we mean $\langle x, y\rangle$?

Comment: What is $T$ here?

Comment: $(T,\mathcal{T},\mu)$ be an arbitrary measure space,

Comment: $a(t,x) := \langle x, t\rangle$ looks like a typo. Something like $a(t,x) = \langle y_j, x\rangle h(t,x)$ would make more sense to me. But to definitely answer this you need to read the paper.